# Symfony2 pass two variables from the service to the Controller $slug

Tags: forms, symfony, service, controller, slug

To clean up my controller code I want to move the "newPostAction" to a service. The problem I get is that now I cannot pass as a result of the funtion in the service two variables to the controller. I use the function to create a form, and the get the slug from the form's post and render it. I do not know how to pass it to the controller. I tried using the "list()" function but it does not get the info right.

How can I call the pos's "slug" from inside the controller?

Here is the controller code:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return array
 *
 * @Route("/new/_post", name="_blog_backend_post_new")
 * @Template("BlogBundle:Backend/Post:new.html.twig")
 */
public function newPostAction(Request $request)
{
    $form_post = $this->getPostManager()->createPost($request);

    $slug_post = ¿How do I get it from inside the createPost()?;

    if (true === $form_post)
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your post was submitted successfully');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_blog_post_show', array('slug' => $slug_post)));
    }

    return array(
        'post_slug' => $slug_post,
        'form_post' => $form_post->createView()
    );
}
```

Here is the PostManager service to create the new post entity:

```
/**
 * Create and validate a new Post
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return bool|FormInterface
 */
public function createPost (Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->setAuthor($this->um->getloggedUser());

    $form_post = $this->formFactory->create(new PostType(), $post);
    $form_post->handleRequest($request);

    $slug_post = $post->getSlug();

    if ($form_post->isValid())
    {
        $this->em->persist($post);
        $this->em->flush();

        return true;
    }

    return $form_post;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return an array from the service and access the values from the controller.

**UPDATE**

Some changes need to be made to your code in order to get things to work.

**Explanation**: when the form is valid, the previous code (I deleted it) returned true therefore `$ret["form_post"]` didn't make sense because `$ret` was not an array. It surprises me that it didn't throw you an error.

Anyway, that could explain why Doctrine didn't persist your entity. Talking about the redirection, the error could be due to the same reason. `$ret` was true (a boolean) and `$ret["form_slug"]` didn't make sense either.

I hope this fixes the problems. Please, let me know if it works.

Service

```
public function createPost (Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->setAuthor($this->um->getloggedUser());

    $form_post = $this->formFactory->create(new PostType(), $post);
    $form_post->handleRequest($request);

    $slug_post = $post->getSlug();

    if ($form_post->isValid())
    {
        $this->em->persist($post);
        $this->em->flush();

        return array("form_post" => true, "slug_post" => $slug_post);;
    }

    return array("form_post" => $form_post, "slug_post" => $slug_post);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function newPostAction(Request $request)
{
    $ret = $this->getPostManager()->createPost($request);

    $form_post = $ret["form_post"];        

    $slug_post = $ret["slug_post"];

    if (true === $form_post)
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your post was submitted successfully');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_blog_post_show', array('slug' => $slug_post)));
    }

    return array(
        'post_slug' => $slug_post,
        'form_post' => $form_post->createView()
    );
}
```

Comment: It does not work. Thank you anyway for your time. The form is displayed however when I submit it the data is not passed to the database nor is redirected. It seems that the return transforms it into a simple string and the content of the form is lost I believe. Any suggestion?